# General::ivar : ... is not a valid variable error in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
xCoordinates = {45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0}
yCoordinates = {0.6, 1.3, 1.5, 2.4, 5, 5.2, 5.3, 6, 6.4, 6.6}
plotData = Transpose@{xCoordinates, yCoordinates}
Show[ListPlot[plotData], Plot[Fit[plotData, {1, x}, x], {x, 0, 45}]]
```

I executed these in order and got 3 errors saying "general::ivar : ... is not a variable" then General::stop : further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. 
The ListPlot is displayed, but without the Fit line. Can anyone please explain where the error in my code is, and what this error means?

**EDIT:** Also generated the messages

```
RGBColor called with 1 argument; 3 or 4 arguments are expected.
```

and

```
Coordinate Skeleton[10] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
```

What do these mean?

Answer (score 1):

See the Details section on [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html).

"Plot has attribute `HoldAll` and evaluates *f* only after assigning specific numerical values to *x*."

To fix the problem evaluate the fit outside of the `Plot` function.

```
xCoordinates = {45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0};
yCoordinates = {0.6, 1.3, 1.5, 2.4, 5, 5.2, 5.3, 6, 6.4, 6.6};
plotData = Transpose@{xCoordinates, yCoordinates};
fit = Fit[plotData, {1, x}, x];
Show[ListPlot[plotData], Plot[fit, {x, 0, 45}]]
```

[image]

Comment: From the documentation: "[`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) is an attribute that specifies that all arguments to a function are to be maintained in an unevaluated form."  This resulted in `Plot` reporting various invalid variable ([ivar](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/General/ivar.html)) errors.

Comment: Or, alternatively, use Evaluate: `Show[ListPlot[plotData], 
 Plot[Evaluate@Fit[plotData, {1, x}, x], {x, 0, 45}]]`